# Image classification: Best approach to training the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

Given a model that has to classify 10 table-cloth items (spoons, forks, cups, plate etc,) and must be tested on an image of a table with all the table-cloth items in it (test_model_accuracy,) which is the best approach for training:

- A: Train the model on individual items then test on test_model_accuracy
- B: Train the model on an entire table with bounding boxes then test on test_model_accuracy
- C: Start with A, then B or vice-versa, then test on test_model_accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy that you will choose depends mainly on the structure of the CNN that you are going to create.

If you train a model that is able to recognize if an image contains a spoon or a fork, you will not be able to test on a table with several table-cloth items (e.g. both a fork and a spoon) because the network will try to answer if in the image there is a spoon or a fork indeed.

Anyway, it is still possible to train the network to classify several features (strategy **"A"**) but in that case you need a model that is able to do Multi-label classification.

Finally, I would suggest to go for the **"B"** strategy because, in my humble opinion, it fits good the application domain.

Hope this answer is clear and helpful!

Cheers.

Comment: If you train on "B" then use the network to train on "A" would it affect performance?

Comment: If think "B" is a more generic approach so you can the trained network also to test on single table-cloth item and/or on a table with multiple table-cloth items.
I think that performance depends mainly on how do you train the model w.r.t. the strategy.